# I am converting date but it add one dot extra with month how to handle it

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am obtaining the current time from the mobile device and changing the format using the following code:

```
  SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss s");
               date_n = currentdate.format(calendar.getTime());
```

However on some mobile devices I am getting the following output

```
Mar.,11,2021 12:08:26 26
```

A dot appears after *Mar*. I don't want that dot. How to handle it?
Any guidelines?

Comment: What are "Some devices"? Do they all have the same system locale?

Comment: use locale DateFormat dfEn = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "dd,MMM,yy", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: means in my device it working ok out is ok but today someone please order and date store like this i don't know why this happening because my datetime format is this(ew SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss s");)

Comment: Do not longer use the outdated SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date API. Use the modern java.time API

Comment: Never use a date-time formatter without a `Locale`. The same thing may be represented differently in different locales. Switch from the outdated `java.util.*` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the Java SE 8 API. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss s",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: I want to know why this is happen  because it works fine but today it generate this type of output

Comment: check your system environment variable :  echo $LANG

Comment: Please do not post code only. Explain what you have done and why

Comment: Bad approach buecause this only works for English, other languages suffer from this where depending on java version it adds or not the dot

Answer (score 6):

Try to [specify a `Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) (somewhere you want):

```
SimpleDateFormat currentdate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss s", Locale.US);
```

Your problem is because how `SimpleDateFormat` displays a month depends on `Locale`. When you omit `Locale`, the default `Locale` of device's setting is used respectively. If the setting of a user's device sets a `Locale` which represents March as *Mar.*, it does so. If you don't want that, you should specify a certain `Locale` explicitly.

Comment: I want to know why this is happen  because it works fine but today it generate this type of output and is this solution works ?

Comment: @MuhammadBasitJamilAbbasi I added an explanation.

Comment: @MuhammadBasitJamilAbbasi a `Locale` does not just determine the language to be used but a specific style for abbreviations of names, too. That means a device with an English locale may abbreviate March by *Mar* or *Mar.*, you won't know. Now think about what might happen when someone uses your app on a device with a Spanish locale, for example. I can tell you the output of this code on my machine: It is `März,11,2021 12:18:41 41`

Comment: ok thanks when I use Locale.English it works fine what ever the language is